# Scala Yield generators

Tags: scala

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)  //Creating a dummy List 

val res1 = for(x <- list1 if x> 3) yield x
// returns res1: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)


val res2 = for(x <- list1) yield{
           if (x>3) x    //Filtering out values lesser then 3
           }

//returns res2: List[AnyVal] = List((), (), (), 4, 5, 6) 
//Expected this to be List(4, 5, 6)
```

How is the above yield returning different results based on the placement of "if" statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the `if` in your `res1` acts as a *filter*. The `if` in `res2` acts as a regular conditional statement.

```
val res1 = for(x <- list1 if x> 3) yield x
```

Using `if` as part of the right hand side of a `<-` statement filters the values of the statement.

```
 for(x <- list1) yield { if (x>3) x }
```

Once a value reaches the yield block, the result of the yield block will be returned, regardless of its type.

In your example, `res2` has produces a value of either `Unit` or `Int` since `if` in this scenario is an expression with a value for either the `if-then` portion or the implicit `else`, which in your case is `Unit`.